# Cannot validate uniqueness in tableless class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have the following code:

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

however, when testing the uniqueness validation I receive:

```
/Users/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@config-keeper/gems/activemodel-3.2.9/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:96:in `rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'UniquenessValidator' (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@config-keeper/gems/activemodel-3.2.9/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:93:in `block in validates'
    from /Users/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@config-keeper/gems/activemodel-3.2.9/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in `each'
    from /Users/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@config-keeper/gems/activemodel-3.2.9/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in `validates'
    from /Users/neil/code/open_source/config_keeper/app/models/foo.rb:8:in `<class:App>'
```

This seems somewhat odd.  Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Comment: actually, uniqueness validation is an AR's validation. So you can't use it without ActiveRecord, sorry.

Comment: What's the logic you want to archive? When you try to validate a uniqueness, you need some other records to compare, since you are using a tableless model, there are not other records to compare in order to check if your attribute is unique or not.

Comment: any validation is an _ActiveModel_'s subsystem. Callbacks. Since Rails 2 ActiveModel behavior is a part of ActiveRecord. You can write everything you want to validate.

Comment: Yet the Uniqueness AR Subsystem will try to validate the uniqueness of your record by making sure that a record doesn't already exists in the database, something that won't work at all because its a tableless model. I totally agree that you can write any validation you want, just that the behavior of the Uniqueness validation is already defined and it doesn't make sense on a tableless model. Am I wrong?

Comment: it makes sense if you convert a tabless model to a database model after validation... imagin a registration process with an active model, which is going through several steps and at the end, the registration will be converted into a user... and before saving, username should be checked..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can leverage ruby's object space to do the following:

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name
  validate do
    if self.name && ObjectSpace.each_object(self.class).select{|o| o.name == self.name }.size > 1
         errors.add(:name,"not unique") 
    end
  end
end

a = Foo.new
b = Foo.new
a.valid? #=> true because of if self.name
a.name = "bar"
a.valid? #=> true because of .size > 1
b.name = "bar"
a.valid? #=> false
b.valid? #=> false
```

This basically walks over every *living* object that matches (or is a subclass of) `Foo`

Answer (score 1):

API:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name
```

Update:

```
validate do
  #uniqueness code
end
```

Comment: Ok, what is :name? According to a code it's just an instance variable wrapped by reader and writer. Uniq what of what?